# iPhone SDK - On Device Locked or On Device Unlocked and application shown

Tags: iphone, uiapplication

I need to find a way to detect when a device has been locked, or else a way to detect when the device has been unlocked, and sent straight to the app where it left off.  Is there some method like:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveAfterLockScreen:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For detecting when phone is being unlocked and application is becoming active again, there is

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

method.

When the device is locked, a method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called.

Both methods belong to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

See [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Those happen at other times too, like an incoming phone call.

Comment: is there a time limit on applicationWillResignActive, like on applicationWillTerminate, how if the function takes more than 5 seconds the function code execution is terminated.